# How to handle authentication from a Node Express redirect to React Client (react-router-dom and useContext)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom, use-context

I am implementing Authorization Code Flow with the Spotify Web API for a simple React app using Node Express for the server and cannot figure out how to pass authentication credentials from the server to the client.

I am using React's useContext hook in order to store authorization credentials.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

// the shape of the default value must match
// the shape that consumers expect
// auth is an object, setAuthData is a function
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  auth: {},
  setAuthData: () => {},
});

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ loading: true, data: null });

  const setAuthData = (data) => {
    setAuth({ data: data });
  };

  // on component mount, set the authorization data to
  // what is found in local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    setAuth({
      loading: false,
      data: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("authData")),
    });
    return () => console.log("AuthProvider...");
  }, []);

  // when authorization data changes, update the local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("authData", JSON.stringify(auth.data));
  }, [auth.data]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuthData: setAuthData }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Inside index.js, I have wrapped my App in AuthProvider

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import AuthProvider from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import App from "./Components/App/AppRouter";

import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Within the App, I am using react-router-dom to manage routing and the protected route.

```
// External libraries
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

// Components
import { PrivateRoute } from "../PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute";

function AppRouter(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={AppLite} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Inside the PrivateRoute, I allow access to the route based on what is in the authentication context.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

import Layout from "../App/Layout";

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { auth, setAuthData } = useContext(AuthContext);

  // if loading is set to true, render loading text
  if (auth.loading) {
    return (
      <Route
        render={() => {
          return (
            <Layout>
              <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </Layout>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  // if the user has authorization render the component,
  // otherwise redirect to the login screen
  return auth.data ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

When the user goes to the home page, they are redirected to the login screen. There, a link redirects the user to /api/login. /api routes are proxied to the node server and /api/login initiates the spotify authorization call. The user is directed to the Spotify login, enters their information and I end up with an access token and refresh token. That all works.

With the access token and refresh token I can redirect the user to a URL with those parameters (e.g. `/#/user/${access_token}/${refresh_token}`) but I'm at a loss how I can get those parameters into my authorization context. Note that getting the tokens from the URL is not the problem.

What I've tried to do is add a useEffect to my PrivateRoute which gets the parameters from the URL and then updates the authorization context if they are found.

```
const { auth, setAuthData } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  // on mounting the component, check the URL for
  // authentication data, if it is present, set
  // it on the authorization context
  useEffect(() => {
    let authData = getHashParams(location);

    authData && setAuthData(authData);

    return () => {
      authData = null;
    };
  }, [location, setAuthData]);
```

However this throws things into an infinite loop. I only seem to be able to successfully use setAuthData when triggered by an onClick event. How should I intercept the redirect from my api router so that I can update the data in the authorization context and then go to the PrivateRoute?

Alternatively, is there a way that I can encapsulate all of my api router logic within an onClick event and get the final response back from it (e.g. `fetch("/api/login")....user gets redirected, fills in info, exchange code for tokens, send tokens back as response...then((response) => setAuthData(response)...`)?

Comment: How about adding `exact={true}` in both routes, or atleast to your private root route `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={AppLite} />`

Answer (score 2):

The core issue here was that I was trying to update the state of a parent component (AuthProvider) from within a child component's useEffect callback. While useContext makes it possible to update the state of a parent component from a child component, doing so with a useEffect will trigger an infinite loop as the setState call becomes a dependency of the useEffect.

Removing authentication from the AppRouter, and moving the URL authentication check into the AuthProvider itself resolved the issue.

Inside index.js, I reordered the component wrapping:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthProvider from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import App from "./Components/App/AppRouter";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Within my AuthContext I am using useLocation from react-router-dom to check the URL for changes and to update the authentication data when a change occurs.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { getHashParams } from "../util/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ loading: true, data: null });
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const setAuthData = (data) => {
    setAuth((state) => ({
      ...state,
      data: data,
    }));
  };

  // on component mount, set the authorization data to
  // what is found in local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    setAuth({
      loading: false,
      data: () => {
        try {
          return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("authData"));
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return null;
        }
      },
    });
  }, []);

  // check the URL for tokens whenever it is updated
  // if authentication tokens are found, update the
  // authentication data and redirect
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkTokens = () => {
      // get authentication tokens from the URL
      // returns null if no hash with parameters in URL
      let tokens = getHashParams(location);
      if (tokens && tokens.path === "error") {
        alert("There was an error during authentication.");
      } else if (tokens) {
        setAuthData(tokens);
        history.replace("/");
      }
    };
    checkTokens();
  }, [location, history]);

  // when authorization data changes, update the local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("authData", JSON.stringify(auth.data));
  }, [auth.data]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuthData]}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

The AppRouter is straightforward.

```
function AppRouter(props) {
  const [auth] = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={App} auth={auth} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

The PrivateRoute simply receives the authentication data as a prop and either renders the component or redirects to the login page.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "../App/Layout";

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
  // if loading is set to true, render loading text
  if (auth.loading) {
    return (
      <Route
        render={() => {
          return (
            <Layout>
              <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </Layout>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  // if the user has authorization render the component,
  // otherwise redirect to the login screen
  return auth.data ? <Component auth={auth.data} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

Now, when the user is redirected from the callback endpoint, the access and refresh tokens are updated in the URL and AuthContext gets updated. With the authentication data updated, the PrivateRoute returns the main app component.

Comment: are you able to provide a snippet of the backend code to see how the auth data is passed back to the frontend?

Comment: The code for the deployed app is up on Github: https://github.com/JonoMacC/fast-tracks (check https://github.com/JonoMacC/fast-tracks/blob/master/server/router.js for the backend router code). As noted, the backend simply provides auth data in the URL.